# Error on Spring Boot App Startup when adding spring-boot-starter-web

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager

Starting a very basic **Spring boot** app using `spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config` to retrieve `AWS sectrets` works correctly. However, the moment I add in the `spring-boot-starter-web dependency` into the project for web service support, `the spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config` `errors` and the application fails to start.

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- if I remove spring-boot-starter-web it all starts properly -->
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

java

```
package com.secrets.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class App
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app_name
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    prefix: /secret
    defaultContext: application
    profileSeparator: _
    failFast: true
    name: app_name
    enabled: true
```

Application should start up normally, however the application errors with the following:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2019-07-03
>   11:57:16.563 ERROR 73839 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'propertySourceBootstrapConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field
>   'propertySourceLocators'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'awsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator'
>   defined in
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerBootstrapConfiguration:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'awsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator' parameter 1; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'aws.secretsmanager-org.springframework.cloud.aws.secretsmanager.AwsSecretsManagerProperties':
>   Could not bind properties to AwsSecretsManagerProperties
>   (prefix=aws.secretsmanager, ignoreInvalidFields=false,
>   ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:187)
>   [spring-cloud-context-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
>   [spring-cloud-context-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
>   [spring-cloud-context-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>   [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]     at
>   com.secrets.demo.App.main(App.java:13) [classes/:na]

Comment: Can you add one sample controller and annotate with @RestController ? than try

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing 1.5.x and 2.x dependencies. Since there are breaking changes between these two version there are often compatibility issues when using both in the same project.

Since spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config only supports 2.x you will need to upgrade spring boot starter parent to a 2.x version.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael McFadyen's reply is correct; however it's also worth noting that manually adding Spring Cloud dependencies and their versions is not a good practice. The `dependencyManagement` plugin and Spring Cloud Release trains should be used instead to ensure that all Spring Cloud libraries used are in compatible versions See the "Release Trains" section in the [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud). It also contains the information on which release trains correspond to which Spring Boot versions.

If you want to be sure that you are correctly setting up Spring dependencies in your build file, you can go to [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/) to generate a project stub with a correct build file.

Comment: Thanks - that's great and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks - that's great and makes sense - all up and running, however as an additional aspect to this I am confused by the utilisation of this library. The limited docs state that "Spring Cloud provides support for centralized configuration, which can be read and made available as a regular Spring PropertySource when the application is started. "  I was expecting to see AWS secrets available as properties to be able to be used using ${prop_name} type syntax. I cannot see that any AWS secrets are read automatically though....have I misunderstood ?